# Working on Java with application that uses jsonapi

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb, json-api

I'm integrating my java application with a service that uses [json:api](http://jsonapi.org/) specification. 
It has rather complex responses due to some service information(links, page info, relationship etc). The problem that I faced is that creating corresponding DTOsfor all the service info plus payload so that jaxb can map that adds a lot of complexity.

As a client I use Spring RestTemplate that is responsible for performing requests and getting response. I need to be able to map the response in a way that all the objects are mapped into appropriate DTOs and service info is also available so that I can use it for making further requests.

I was thing about several options here:

- Making parameterized class that can hold different types of payload and also provide service info.
- Parsing sections manually(extracting payload and service info) and setting it to some object that holds both - payload and service info.
- Using external library to serialize/deserialize data. Here I found several options: [winterchord/jsonapi](https://github.com/winterchord/jsonapi) and [jasminb/jsonapi-converter](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter).

What approach is more common and applicable for solving this task and having reliable, but still light-weight solution?

Comment: I have used multiple times **RestTemplate**. I normally implement a package with all the services (https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/track-hub-registrator/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/pride/utilities/trackhub/registry/TrackHubRegistryClient.java). You can implement the DAO using (https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/track-hub-registrator/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/pride/utilities/trackhub/registry/model/Species.java). POM file (https://github.com/PRIDE-Utilities/track-hub-registrator/blob/master/pom.xml).

Comment: You can use for the mapping: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>X.X.X</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @ypriverol how do you handle service information given by jsonapi or other specifications within RestTemplate? That is the most difficult part here if we just use jaxb.

Comment: I use com.fasterxml.jackson.core see the examples. You can use the annotations using: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Species {
    @JsonProperty("scientific_name")
    String scientificName;` The JsonProperty will enable you to map the specific fields from the json into your object model. The @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation in your class is important in case you have null values in the json output.